# Should I use breadcrumbs when they are valid on only a few pages throughout the website?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am currently working on a website that does not have a lot of content. I've read that breadcrumbs should be used when there's 2+ levels of content. In my case mostly there are just two levels - home page and its subpages. But then there's Support subpage which then redirects to its subpages, so we have: Home>Support>FAQ.

I am wondering if I should:

1) use breadcrumbs just when there are more levels to the content (at the expense of consistency)

2) use breadcrumbs throughout the website, so it's consistent, although there would mostly be Home>Blog or Home>Contact which is not really good, because those subpages have their own headings, so there's gonna be information overload

3) not use breadcrumbs at all, even on those 3-steps subpages.

Personally I am leaning towards the 3rd option, but I've been struggling with it for a while now, so I thought to reach out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 makes the most sense.

Users will most likely not get lost on the second level of your website/app, but if more then 2 levels are there the chance of getting lost gets much higher, in this moment users will look for breadcrumbs and this is the time to display them.

Comment: Isn't it wrong considering consistency? That I sometimes do display them and sometimes I don't? I get your point, after all it was one of my own proposition, however I'm not sure I feel it. Can you provide any research or grounded knowledge behind that option?

Comment: Consistency is given if you display breadcrumbs consistent as soon as there are 2+ levels.